# Error with rake db:migrate with rails 4.1 on Mavericks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I just upgraded my OS X from 10.7.5 to 10.9.3.

I've done the following:
- Upgraded ruby to 2.1.2 (and using it)
- bundle install succeeded
- installed postgres, server running.

```
$rails server -p 5000
```

works (the server runs)

- However, when I do

  `$rake db:migrate`

It gives me the following error:

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant AbstractController::Error
/Users/ppd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:8:in `<module:AbstractController>'
/Users/ppd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/ppd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/haml-3.1.6/lib/haml/helpers/rails_323_textarea_fix.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/ppd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/haml-3.1.6/lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:260:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/ppd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/haml-3.1.6/lib/haml/template.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/ppd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/haml-3.1.6/lib/haml.rb:41:in `block in init_rails'
/Users/ppd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/haml-3.1.6/lib/haml.rb:41:in `each'
/Users/ppd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/haml-3.1.6/lib/haml.rb:41:in `init_rails'
/Users/ppd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/haml-3.1.6/lib/haml/railtie.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/ppd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
/Users/ppd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
/Users/ppd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
/Users/ppd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
/Users/ppd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
/Users/ppd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/haml-3.1.6/lib/haml/railtie.rb:15:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/ppd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
/Users/ppd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
/Users/ppd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/Users/ppd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
/Users/ppd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
/Users/ppd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application/bootstrap.rb:76:in `block in <module:Bootstrap>'
/Users/ppd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/Users/ppd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/ppd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/Users/ppd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/Users/ppd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:288:in `initialize!'
/Users/ppd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
/Users/ppd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
/Users/ppd/Academics/Research/git/teapot/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/ppd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:264:in `require_environment!'
/Users/ppd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:367:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/Users/ppd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/ppd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I can't seem to find anything on this on google/SO. I'd really appreciate help with it!

Comment: Stupid question, are you using pg gem and updated database.yml ?

Comment: Very valid question. I am using the pg gem version 0.15.1. What does updated database.yml mean? Does the format for database.yml in rails4 different from that in rails 3.2.1? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually, in 4.1, it did, but keeps backwards compatibility.(You can use stuff like development: <<: *default to stop repeating code for multiple databases)
I asked with another purpose, though, I was asking if you have the database configured to psql, with the right adapter and so on..?

Comment: Here's my database.yml

development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: postgres
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  username: <username>

test: &TEST
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: postgres
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  username: <username>

how can check if the right adaptor is configured?

Comment: An update on this: even "$rake about" gives the same error. So you were likely right all along; it seems to be a problem with the DB adapter.

Comment: What happens when you run `bundle exec rake db:migrate`?

Comment: @arran-scott, I get the exact same error.

Comment: Ok, have you tried creating a new project with `rails new`?
Something like `rails new test`, then run `rake about`

Comment: @ArranScott, I tried `$ rails new testapp`, and `$ rake about`. It works. The default db adaptor is sqlite3, whereas mine is postgresql. That seems to be the problem. I've also uninstalled and reinstalled postgres, but still get the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't figured out the details of it, but apparently Haml is the culprit here.

Remove `gem 'haml-rails'` from your Gemfile if you have it, and replace it with:

```
gem 'haml', '~> 4.0.0'
```

Then run `bundle update` and boot up the Rails server again.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! This worked! And I am kicking myself for not having figured it out on my own.

Comment: Framework errors like these are tough to figure out, I guess I was lucky to find a solution ;) Glad I could help!